# MD5 in vb6 hash password

Tags: mysql, hash, vb6, vb6-migration

How to write md5 hash in vb6 ?

I wrote this syntax but it gives me error in SQL MariaDB:

> check the manual that corresponds your MariaDB version for the right
>   syntax to use near'(32),HashBytes ('MD5','Text2'),2

```
INSERT INTO student (Student_id,password,firstname)VALUES ('" & Text1.Text &" ' , CONVERT( NVARCHAR (32),HashBytes ('MD5' ,'"&Text2.Text&"'        ),2),'"&Text3.Text&"')"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are three resources for you:

[Listing of MD5 Class for Visual Basic](http://www.bullzip.com/md5/vb/md5-vb-class.htm)

[cMD5.cls](http://codes-sources.commentcamarche.net/source/view/27271/941398#browser)

[MD5 Hash Calculator for VB6](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vb6md5hashcode/)